# One Slave for many master BIND server

Tags: bind

I have 3 servers. All have BIND installed.

One server is for company site only - call it s0.

Two servers are used for hosting accounts - call it s1 and s2.

Is it possible to use s0 as SLAVE for s1 and s2 ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add as many master zones and slave zones to each server as you like.

So one server can handle a master zone and also be the slave of another servers master. Of course the can only be one master for a certain zone, but many slaves of course.

Comment: How should I configure it ?
s0: 192.168.0.1 - MASTER for s0 and SLAVE for s1 and s2
s1: 192.168.0.10 - MASTER
s2: 192.168.0.100 - MASTER